# Searched data not loading to the data grid view in asp.net form?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, search, datagridview

**when i click search it will be search by name on table.(refer image 1)**

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAPf3.png)

**My search code**

```
protected void srchbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.TextBox1.Text))
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Search name is empty!')</script>");
               
            }
            else
            {

                con.Open();
                adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select Convert(nvarchar(10),Date,121) as Date,Department,KaizenLead,Type,Observation,Onetimereapeat,Typeofwaste,Rootcase,ImageBefore,ImageAfter,Before,After,Improvement,Savings,Impleteam,validateby,Rootcase,safetyadmin,convert(nvarchar(10),Implementationdate,121) as Implementationdate,Status,Reason,FinanceRef  from GembaKaizen where KaizenLead like '" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);
                dt = new DataTable();
                adapt.Fill(dt);
                gv_case.DataSource = dt;//gv_gase-grid view name
                con.Close();

                
            }
           
        }
        catch(SqlException)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Database error!')</script>");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                    con.Open();
                    adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select Convert(nvarchar(10),Date,121) as Date,Department,KaizenLead,Type,Observation,Onetimereapeat,Typeofwaste,Rootcase,ImageBefore,ImageAfter,Before,After,Improvement,Savings,Impleteam,validateby,Rootcase,safetyadmin,convert(nvarchar(10),Implementationdate,121) as Implementationdate,Status,Reason,FinanceRef  from GembaKaizen where KaizenLead like '" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adapt.Fill(ds);
                    gv_case.DataSource = ds;
                    gv_case.DataBind();
                    con.Close();
```

Comment: i found ANSWER :)

Comment: You problem is you declared datatable as datatable() - that means an array of data tables, and that will not work. But dataset() is already a array of tables. And once again, it should have been declared as dataSet, not dataset(). I would go back to declaring a data table, as you working with one query, and it more clear, and better yet, if you write code, then you don't need (or want) a table qualifier such as ds.tables(0).Rows, and you can use ds.Rows. So tossing mud at the wall and willy nilly changing from a datatable to dataset() array works, better to be clear in code and use datatable

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem, but I can see two problems with your code:

1. The like clause in the sql query needs `%` otherwise it's just equality

```
like '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'"
```

2. Sql injection
   Always add user input as parameter in your query, otherwise you are prone to sql injection